# Can't get pop down menus to do anything in KDE/QT application GUIs in Ubuntu (Gnome session)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, gui

I have a brand new install of Ubuntu 10.10 x64 in an attempt to solve the following problem from my previous 10.04 x86 install, but with the exact same problem persisting. When trying to run Amarok or Skype, which I am told produce their GUI component via the KDE and QT frameworks ( I may be misusing these terms but I hope my point comes across ), both of these applications fail to produce menus when a menu producing button is clicked. This of course, makes both of these apps useless.

I installed both apps through the Ubuntu software manager, so expected that any KDE runtime dependencies would have been taken care of already. I then installed kdelibs manually from the console, which didn't appear to be installed already, but this didn't seem to change anything. I installed a QT GUI settings management application to see if somehow menus were turned off or something for QT applications, but the QT settings application itself appears to suffer from the same lack of popdown menus... I don't have this problem with any of my Gnome apps.

What is wrong here? How can I make these applications work?

Comment: this could be caused by a broken theme engine, if Qt is using the same GTK theme. Try changing the theme.

Comment: By the way, "QT" = "QuickTime" = Video technology from Apple; "Qt" = "Cute" = GUI cross-platform toolkit from Trolltech/Nokia

Comment: I have had sketchy performance from ubuntu on menus for both GTK and Qt recently.  Thinking Juliano is right on the themes.  I even had GDM crash during startup when applying theme (in my case I tracked it back to the gnome settings manager app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It appears that the menus in question relied upon 'visual effects' being enabled in the 'Appearances' section of the user preferences. Turning visual effects to either normal or extra thus fixes this problem.